# How to get the text of all elements in protractor and compare it with my expected text?

Tags: typescript, npm, protractor, node-modules, cucumberjs

This is my first post and looking out for some help as I am new to protractor.

I want to get the text of all the web elements under div tag and compare the text with my expected text.I have found a way to get the text using below :

```
 element.all(By.xpath("//div[@class='grid-x grid-row 
   gridBody']/div")).each(function(element, index){
  element.getText().then(function(text) {
  console.log(''+text+'');
  })
  })
```

but, I want to know how to compare this text with my exepected. Inshort, I want to know how assertion can be done in the above scenario.

Note:Please don't tell me that this question is already posted because in previous questions I could find a solution to get the text of all the webelements but not a way to compare it with my Expected text.

Kindly, let me know if you require any other information.

I have tried using the below but I don't think its a good practice:

```
if(index===0){
expect(text).equals("Campaign Title");
console.log("Step passed");
}
```

---

Thanks for the help.But,actually that didn't help me.Please find the below updated code:

```
       Then(/^User clicks and gets all the text for header details$/, async() => {
    await search.headerActiveCampaign.each(function(element, index){
        element.getText().then(function(text) {
            console.log(''+text+''); 
         expectedTextArray[]=['Campaign Title','Order Number','Air 
        Dates','Amounts','Status'] 
        expect(search.headerActiveCampaign.getText()).toBe(expectedArray); 
       });      
       })
       });
```

Here, in this "search.headerActiveCampaign" search is the page object and headerActiveCampaign is the webelement like below:

```
     public headerActiveCampaign: ElementArrayFinder;
    this.headerActiveCampaign=element.all(By.xpath("//div[@class='grid-x 
     grid- row gridHead']"));
```

expectedTextArray[] is throwing me an error that its unable to find it.What should I do now?Kindly, update the code .

---

In my pages.ts file, I have written in the below format:

```
     import { $, ElementFinder , element,By, by, ElementArrayFinder} from "protractor";
     export class SearchPageObject {
     public headerActiveCampaign: ElementArrayFinder;

     constructor() {
     this.headerActiveCampaign=element.all(By.xpath("//div[@class='grid-x grid-row           gridHead']"));
      }
      }
```

So, if I use "const" right its not working and in the below declaration its not identifying expectedTextArray although I declare it as "const"

```
      expect(search.headerActiveCampaign.getText()).toBe(expectedTextArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        const headerActiveCampaign = element.all(By.xpath("//div[@class='grid-x grid-row gridBody']/div");// paste this IN YOUR PAGE object FILE.

       const expectedTextArray[]=['',''] //Add the text that you expect as array

        //Now to compare the actual and expect use the below code.
Then(/^User clicks and gets all the text for header details$/, async() => {

        expect(search.headerActiveCampaign.getText()).toBe(expectedTextArray); 
       });      
       })
       });
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: @AmrishSukumaran please do *not* edit their answer to reply to them. Either write a comment or edit your question with the updated code.

Comment: @Madhan  I have tried the suggestion which you had given earlier, but thats not working for me.I have updated the question, please have a look at it and let me know your comments.

Comment: @AmrishSukumaran please try the updated answer. Let me know if that does not HELP YOU.

Comment: @Madhan I have updated the question.I have changed as per your suggestion, but its actuallt not identifying the declaration using "const" keyword

Comment: @AmrishSukumaran Try removing `const` it may be because of the declaration.